# Should we sand and prime holes in our walls or pay someone to do it?

Tags: sanding, primer

We just had our 1,000-square-foot house insulated with blown-in insulation. Now we have 180 patched-up holes in our interior walls that need be sanded and primed before we repaint. The holes themselves are about two inches in diameter; the plaster goes out anywhere from six inches to a foot.

How difficult and time-consuming would it be to sand and prime the holes ourselves? If I estimate five minutes per hole, I get 15 hours; is that realistic?

We have one estimate for $1200. That seems like a lot for something we could theoretically do ourselves, especially when we have other upcoming projects that will require professional work.

Should we get another estimate, pay the $1200, or do it ourselves?

Comment: Invest in a palm sander, and it might be even less than 5 min per hole.  (assuming you already have the area cleared out, so you don't have to worry about dust containment, and just a simple drop cloth for the paint)

Answer (score 4):

If the holes are already patched and all your are doing is sanding it down to a smooth finish before you prime, it will be way less than 5 minutes per patch.

Personally I would do it myself but how valuable your time is something only you can answer.  If you get the sand paper made specifically for sanding joint compound (like [this](http://solutions.3m.com/wps/portal/3M/en_US/Manufacturing/Industry/Product-Catalog/Online-Catalog/?PC_7_RJH9U5230GE3E02LECFTDQGLE0_nid=8432KMH1WZgsSQSFJR0R56gl6JRQSJ16QZbl) it will go really fast.  Obviously doing the whole house will take a while but I think your esitmate of 5 minutes per patch it high.  Though if you pay someone else, would they be doing "wet sanding" to reduce the amount of dust in the rooms (that is something I have not done and I don't know how much harder it would be)?  That may be a consideration unless your rooms are already a mess from the actual insulation procedure.

Answer (score 3):

You're looking at about 1 minute of sanding per small patch, not 5.  However, you'll be looking at a LOT of dust.

In my experience, a $20 vacuum sander can SERIOUSLY reduce the dust.

[image]

After you sand, take a large clean sponge and just dampen it slightly and go over each spot gently with the sponge to get a near mirror smooth finish on the drywall.  Even with 180 holes you're seriously only looking at a couple of hours to finish the job.